# ValueError: could not convert string to float: EdfVersion=3.0

Tags: python, csv

I want to make these lists of strings into lists of floats in order to create a x und a y list. The end goal is a plot.

1. `['156873.0559997559', '601451.77']`
2. `['156883.0700073242', '601369.34']`
3. `['156893.0839996338', '601401.88']` ...

If I try it with the attached code, I will get this error: could not convert string to `float: EdfVersion=3.0`.

```
x =[]
y=[]
with open('C:/Users/A/Desktop/test.txt') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')

for row in plots:
   x= x.append(float(row[0]))
   y= y.append(float(row[1]))
   print x
```

Comment: What language is that?

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to use `csv` here:

```
x = []
y = []

with open('C:/Users/A/Desktop/test.txt') as filename:
    for line in filename:
        line = line.strip().lstrip('[').rstrip(']').split(', ')
        x.append(float(line[0].strip("'")))
        y.append(float(line[1].strip("'")))

print x

[156873.0559997559, 156883.0700073242, 156893.0839996338]
```